# FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds

Tags: mongoimport

I have json file with below content :

```
laks@giis:/home/ubuntu# cat /tmp/db1.json
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54cf54e57f7cfa64c908ebd2" }, "tid" : 1, "__v" : 0 }
```

and it imports properly:

```
laks@giis:/home/ubuntu# mongoimport -d test -c tutorials --file /tmp/db1.json 
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Tue May  5 03:44:25.471 imported 1 objects
```

but when I added date field to the same db.json file it fails:

```
laks@giis:/home/ubuntu# cat /tmp/db1.json 
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "54cf54e57f7cfa64c908ebd2" }, "tid" : 1, "__v" : 0,"time" : { "$date" : "2015-02-01T22:09:31.475-0500" } }


laks@giis:/home/ubuntu# mongoimport -d test -c tutorials --file /tmp/db1.json 
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Tue May  5 03:45:17.729 exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds: offset:92
Tue May  5 03:45:17.729 
Tue May  5 03:45:17.729 check 0 0
Tue May  5 03:45:17.729 imported 0 objects
Tue May  5 03:45:17.729 ERROR: encountered 1 error(s)
```

Other solutions like add "--jsonArray"  in the cli , didn't help.

Comment: What version of `mongoimport` are you using (as reported by `mongoimport --version`)? Your test JSON imports fine for me using `mongoimport` 2.6.9 and 3.0.2. Based on the error message ("Date expecting integer milliseconds"), it looks like you are using an older version of mongoimport that only supports milliseconds.  You can either upgrade to a newer production release of MongoDB, or format your `$date` strings in milliseconds as required.

Comment: I don't have access to that machine for another 12hrs. Will update the results later today. thanks!

Comment: Pls move your comment to answer part! It worked after upgrading mongodb-2.6! (I was using 2.4) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of mongoimport are you using (as reported by mongoimport --version)? Your test JSON imports fine for me using mongoimport 2.6.9 and 3.0.2. Based on the error message ("Date expecting integer milliseconds"), it looks like you are using an older version of mongoimport that only supports milliseconds. You can either upgrade to a newer production release of MongoDB, or format your $date strings in milliseconds as required.